# What is the SDE of this equation?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, risk-management, finance-mathematics

I am new and struggling to understand how to solve this using Ito lemma.

Can someone please explain it to me:

$$dS_t=-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 S_t dW_t$$

what is the solution with explanation please

Answer (score 3):

Actually this is just the Black-Scholes SDE with zero drift and $-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2$ volatility. If you plug that into the well known solution, you get $S_t=S_0e^{\frac{1}{8}\sigma^4t-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 W_t}$ but let's calculate it with Ito's formula.

Choose $f(x)=\log(x)$, then we have $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $f''(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}$.
Inserting in Ito's formula yields
$$
d\log(S_t)=\frac{1}{S_t}dS_t+\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{1}{S_t^2}\right)d\langle S\rangle_t
\\ =-\frac{1}{S_t}\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S_tdW_t+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{S_t^2}\frac{1}{4}\sigma^4S_t^2dt \\
= \frac{1}{8}\sigma^4dt-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2dW_t
$$
or equivalently
$$
\log(S_t)=\log(S_0)+\frac{1}{8}\sigma^4 t-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2W_t \\
\Leftrightarrow S_t=S_0\exp\left(\frac{1}{8}\sigma^4t-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2W_t\right)
$$

Comment: Why is it not (-1/8sigma^4t...)

Comment: @InfoLearner you mean why it is the exponential of that? Because you have to get rid of the logarithm that we applied to use Ito's formula